# Flex how to specify the application encoding?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application
```

is that xml attribute `encoding="utf-8"` making the whole application in utf-8?, also the input forms and others? or where do I specify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The encoding you are referring to is the xml document encoding.](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_encoding.asp)
This tells the editor/compiler what the character definitions are.
Go ahead and change it to utf-16

What you want it the [restrict](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/SkinnableTextBase.html#restrict) property on the textinput